# Password reset confirmation link redirects to page not found 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

```
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FILED': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION':True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION':True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL':True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE':True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL':True,
    'SERIALIZERS':{
        'user_create': 'app1.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'app1.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    } 
}
```

**Here it works fine:** You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at localhost:8000.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

```
http://localhost:8000/password/reset/confirm/MTI/bep1bq-486f1f58d396e13f7bdf862a12ba0a18
```

In case you've forgotten username or localhost

```
 username: m**********0@gmail.com
 localhost:8000 team
```

**I want to:**  when I click on this link, it should navigate to the page that I customized to set a new password, but It redirects to a page not found

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/password/reset/confirm/MTI/bep1bq-486f1f58d396e13f7bdf862a12ba0a18
```

Please anyone knows how to solve this issue))?